# if (confirm) ajax not working in cancel bottun

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-blade

this is my conde . that confirmation window shows up, but whether I press "confirm" or "cancel" it would delete data anyway. Can you help me out?

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-repeater-delete]', function () {

    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this element?')) {
        var el = $(this).parent().parent();
        var id = $(el.find('.id')).val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '{{route('invoice.product.destroy')}}',
            type: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': jQuery('#token').val()
            },
            data: {
                'id': id
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {

            },
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: Needs a [mcve] - as it looks like your code would only run the ajax if you click "Ok" on the confirm dialog. eg/ https://jsfiddle.net/rfc2ex64/

Comment: You have either another click event registered for the `data-repeater-delete` selector, or that element might be part of a form. Since the confirm window is blocking, the default form submit (or the other refgistered event) would run after your confirm window gets closed, no matter what you pressed